# Can I call a function from a 32 bit dll using external C call in Dymola

Tags: c, modelica, dymola

I'm trying to call a function from a 32 bit dll in Dymola.

Below is from the command line.

```
Must translate function Library.CopyDesign.
Compilation of function Library.CopyDesign successful.
Finished 
Process Execute function Library.CopyDesign stopped without any error indication.
Failed to execute command Library.CopyDesign.
Failed to expand Library.CopyDesign
```

The simulation log is empty.

I don't have a lot of experience working with C, and debugging C code in Dymola.

I was able to test to test the function using a standalone C program using a 32 bit gcc compiler.

Would like to know if calling a function from a 32 bit dll using external C call in Dymola is possible in the first place.

Below is the modelica code

```
function CopyDesign
input String I_RPath;
input String I_NPath;
input Integer I_Flags;
input Integer I_Serie;
input Integer I_Mode;
input String I_Typ;
input Integer I_CC;
input String I_Ref;
input Real I_Q;
input Real I_T0;
input Real I_TC;
input Real I_TS;
input Real I_TL;
input Real I_TN;
input Integer I_NET;
input Integer I_DS;
input Integer I_OV;
input Integer I_FI;
input Real I_FCF;
input Integer I_FCV;
input Integer I_FCOF;
input Integer I_FCMV;
input Integer I_OP;
input Real I_CR;

output String O_T1;
output Integer O_SzT1;

output String O_T2;
output Integer O_SzT2;

output TDesignData DesignData;

output Integer O_Hint1;
output Integer O_Hint2;

output String O_Err;
output Integer O_SzErr;

output Integer ReturnValue;

external"C" ReturnValue = CopyDesign(
I_RPath,
I_NPath,
I_Flags,
I_Serie,
I_Mode,
I_Typ,
I_CC,
I_Ref,
I_Q,
I_T0,
I_TC,
I_TS,
I_TL,
I_TN,
I_NET,
I_DS,
I_OV,
I_FI,
I_FCF,
I_FCV,
I_FCOF,
I_FCMV,
I_OP,
I_CR,
O_T1,
O_SzT1,
O_T2,
O_SzT2,
DesignData,
O_Hint1,
O_Hint2,
O_Err,
O_SzErr) annotation (LibraryDirectory="modelica://Library/",
Library="Hhk52");
end CopyDesign;
```

Comment: It should be possible. Can you show the Modelica code?

Comment: Added the modelica code in the question, due to character limit in the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Yes calling .DLLs from Dymola is possible. We do this for a lot of cases but can be a bit complicated to setup.
You need:

1. .DLL (either 64/32 bit or both)
2. A C type header file in order to access the function
3. A .LIB file which can be exported from the .DLL.

In the MSL you can find some .DLL examples:

> Modelica.Utilities.Strings.length

```
pure function length "Return length of string"
  extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
  input String string;
  output Integer result "Number of characters of string";
external "C" result = ModelicaStrings_length(string) annotation(IncludeDirectory="modelica://Modelica/Resources/C-Sources", Include="#include \"ModelicaStrings.h\"", Library="ModelicaExternalC");
```

**Creating a .LIB file from .DLL** ([external link](https://www.asawicki.info/news_1420_generating_lib_file_for_dll_library))

1. Open Visual Studio command prompt (2010 works)
2. Create .def file from the .dll. e.g.

> ```
> dumpbin /exports C:\Users\**DLLNAME**.dll > C:\Users\**DLLNAME**.def
> ```

3. Edit .def file (manually) so that it contains the keyword: "EXPORTS" followed by all function definitions only
4. You can now create the .Lib file with the following command (x64 for 64 bit or x86 for 32 bit .DLL):

> ```
> lib /def:C:\Users\**DLLNAME**.def /out:C:\Users\**DLLNAME**.lib /machine:x64
> ```

5. The .lib file should now be created and can be used in Dymola

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was able to create the .lib file, It is compiling, but fails to execute giving the same error `Process Execute function C_series.Library.CopyDesign stopped without any error indication.
Failed to execute command C_series.Library.CopyDesign.
Failed to expand C_series.Library.CopyDesign(` Will try to debug the c code.